# Ajax $_POST call to PHP $_SESSION returns out of date information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I don't understand what is happening here. I have three pages.

- Home.php
- Nearmiss.php
- Reports.php

Each of these pages has the following code at the top, with their own "thispage" variable defined specific to that page.

```
<?php
    // home.php
    if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
      session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['thispage'] = 'Home';
    echo('<div id="thispage" hidden>' . $_SESSION['thispage'] . '</div>')
?>
```

When I open each page and inspect the source I see exactly what I should see in that the hidden div contains the correct name of the page.  However my app has an a function inside it that I'm trying to use to monitor $_SESSION in javascript for testing purposes. I'm doing an ajax call to logsession.php (below).

```
<?php
    // logsession.php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
          session_start();
        }
        echo( json_encode( $_SESSION ) );
    }
?>
```

My javascript function is written like this, and it just does a post to logsession.php and logs the results to the console.

```
let app = (function() {
    var session = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "includes/logsession.php",
            dataType: "json"
        }).then( function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        });
    }
    return {
        session : session
    }
}());
```

Can be called at the console using `app.session();`

I would expect to see the two of these synchronized as I click between pages, but when I log the session to console as I click between my navigation they do not match, with the ajax call often lagging one click behind the page I'm actually on.  So for example, I'll go from "Home.php" to "Reports.php" and I will get a null value (as if $_SESSION hasn't been set yet) or I'll get { thispage: "Home" } when clearly I just navigated to Reports.php.

My navigation is done with bootstrap.

```
<!-- Navbar Left -->
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="lnkHome"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="lnkNearmiss"><a href="#">Nearmiss</a></li>
      <li id="lnkReports"><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

My navbar is setup so that styles are applied automatically when clicked using some javascript in a refresh function, which just adds and removes an "active" class to it with some styles.  Inside this I'm calling my session.

```
let refresh = (function() {
    var navbar = function( element ) {
        $('#navbar ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(element).addClass('active');
        app.session();
    }
return {
        navbar : navbar
    }
}());
```

The click events that are wiring up my links to the `refresh.navbar();` function look like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#lnkHome', function() {
    if ( $('#thispage').html() != 'Home' ) {
        // note, references the content of the hidden divs
        refresh.navbar( this );
    }
});
```

As I'm clicking through my links this is what I see.  Starting on the Home.php, I clicked sequentially through every few seconds to Nearmiss.php and then Reports.php and you can see that sometimes its fine and then its not, which you can see on the last two clicks.

- Count 20 was actually on Nearmiss.php
- Count 21 was actually on Reports.php

Timestamps included.

[image: Google Chrome console showing app.session(); log]

Why would Ajax ever return old information?

Environment
 - Local web server on my LAN, latency is non-existent.
 - Hitting the web server by IP address (no dns / proxy crazy routing)
 - Bootstrap 3.3.7
 - jQuery 3.1.1
 - PHP 7.1

Comment: You need to call **session_start()** even if the session has already been established.  I wouldn't bother with **session_status()**

Comment: `session_start();` is being called on every page like that.  The reason that is done is because having multiple php files with `session_start();` in them loading at the same time throws a warning.  Since I'm trying to be a good little programmer and do it "the right way" so I wrap it that way instead of using `@session_start();` to suppress the warnings because its considered lazy.

Comment: The "right way" would be to create a single file that contains your session start logic and require or include it into the pages that need it.

Comment: That is actually a really good idea, and I think I'm going to do that... however I'm not sure if that would change anything about my problem here since we know absolutely that $_SESSION is being started correctly in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my server, with PHP 7+, **session_status()** always returns **PHP_SESSION_NONE**.

```
<?php
if ( session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
        session_start();
        echo 'Session started<br>';
}
echo 'Session established';
$_SESSION['this'] = 'that';
```

It looks like you're trying to build a page hit counter.  This is how I would do it:

**session.php**

```
session_start();
$page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.php');
// Check if there is a session variable for this page
// If there isn't one, initialize one to zero
if (!isset($_SESSION[$page])) {
        $_SESSION[$page] = 0;
}
$_SESSION[$page]++;
var_dump($_SESSION);  // Debug only
```

**some-page.php**

```
require_once 'session.php';
```